# No alive nodes found in your cluster (FacetFlow)

Tags: elasticsearch

This is my code :

```
        $source_hosts = [
            'http://azure-xxxxxxxxxxx.west-eu.azr.facetflow.io'
        ];

        $source_client = \Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()
            ->setHosts($source_hosts)->build();

        $params = [
            'index' => 'dir',
            'type' => 'article',
            'id' => '1',
            'body' => ['id' => 1,'name' => "article"]
        ];

        $response = $source_client->index($params);
        print_r($response);
```

testing from localhost
i have the error bellow :

> No alive nodes found in your cluster

Comment: Check what you get with `curl http://azure-xxxxxxxxxxx.west-eu.azr.facetflow.io` and if you don't get anything, it means your cluster is down or unreachable and you might need to restart it.

Comment: He is working : 
{"status":200,"name":"gw1..................}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must disable sslCertificate :

```
$source_client = \Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()
            ->setSSLVerification(false)
            ->setHosts($hosts)->build();
```

thanks every body