# No alive nodes found in your cluster | connection refused (Docker, PHP)

Tags: php, laravel, docker, elasticsearch

**UPDATED INFO**

With `dd($clientBuilder->transport->getLastConnection()->getLastRequestInfo());`

I could log out the following

```
    "curl" => array:2 [
      "error" => "Failed to connect to localhost port 30003: Connection refused"
```

But the thing is **Elasticsearch is available** under localhost:30003 via the web browser

The sample output when reaching this site:

```
{

    "name": "xyz",
    "cluster_name": "docker-cluster",
...
}
```

I did configure the host

```
        $clientBuilder = ClientBuilder::create()
            ->setHosts(['http://localhost:30003/'])
            ->build();
```

When I `dd($clientBuilder)`, the host is set to localhost:30003

```
          #serializer: SmartSerializer {#385 …}
          #transportSchema: "http"
          #host: "localhost:30003"
          #path: "/"
```

Again, the server is up and running, I can reach it via the web browser but I still get the error message:

> No alive nodes found in your cluster

- **Elasticsearch version:** 6.7.0
- **Elasticsearch PHP Version:** 6.7.0 (latest)

In my **docker-compose** file, I'm mapping the port 30003 to 9200

```
      ports:
        - "30003:9200"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No alive nodes found in your cluster (FacetFlow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37148331/no-alive-nodes-found-in-your-cluster-facetflow)

Comment: Edited. Unfortunately, it did not help

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch **did not cause the error.**

cURL had an **error 7** which means that it **could not establish a connection.**

My solution I came up with was the following:

```
        $clientBuilder = ClientBuilder::create()
            ->setHosts([
                [
                    'host' => 'docker.for.mac.localhost',
                    'port' => '30003'
                ]
            ])
            ->build();
```

**I switched from localhost to docker.for.mac.localhost**

This helped because I'm using docker container and each container has a different ip adress